# How can I export all my VPN PPTP connections to known Ubuntu machines?

Tags: internet, vpn, connection, pptp

I have a lot of VPN connections and wonder how can I ease the process of exporting or entering them all at once (about 50) to any of my Ubuntu machines. There should be an application for synchronizing your VPN connections, say using Gmail (like an Android app does) or something of that nature.

Is there a solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Archive (a.k.a. "zip") those 50 connections from the `/etc/PPP/peers` with their configurations in a file and unzip them at the other computer also in the `/etc/PPP/peers` directory.

This is how you can achieve what you want.